# Storing information from a file into a structure in C - running into segmentation fault

Tags: c, file, io, scanf, structure

I am writing a program to store information from an input file and print out information as selected by the user. I have not gotten to the use selection part yet but I am running into a segmentation fault right off the bat. I know that this means that I am trying to access places in memory that either don't exist or that I cannot access.

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. I am trying to store the information from the input file into my structure.

The input file is in this format

```
3
5 Name Name 10 56789
7 Name Name 7 67894
8 Name Name 10 89375
```

I have tried to access the structures directly as emp[1].id etc instead of emp[i].id and such. This also did not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// structures
struct emp
{
    int id;
    char firstname[10];
    char lastname[10];
    int department;
    float salary;
} emp[10];


// function prototypes
// nothing here yet

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i = 0;
int choice;

if(argc != 2){

printf("Usage: %s input.txt\n", argv[0]);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

FILE* inputFile;


inputFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if(inputFile == NULL){
            printf("Error opening %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
// file is open now

// loop to save information from file into structure

 int num;

    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &num);


            for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", emp[i].id);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%s", emp[i].firstname);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%s", emp[i].lastname);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", emp[i].department);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%f", emp[i].salary);

}


    printf("\n");
    printf("Welcome to the Employee Database!\n");
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    printf("Choose an option:\n");
    printf("1:   Print empid\n");
    printf("2:   Print ALL employees\n");
    printf("3:   Show ALL employees in department\n");
    printf("-1:  QUIT\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

// I have not set up the functions to perform the selection options yet 
return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I am receiving.

```
c803@cs2:~A5$ gcc A5.c
c803@cs2:~A5$ ./a.out input.txt
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: What does the debugger say about the crash?

Comment: Always enable compiler warnings: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 A5.c`

Comment: maybe `num`is larger than `10`?

Comment: A5.c:60:29: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but       argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
         fscanf(inputFile, "%d", emp[1].id);
                             ^
A5.c:63:29: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
         fscanf(inputFile, "%d", emp[1].department);
                             ^



I will work to see if I can solve these issues now. Thank you.

Comment: SERIOUSLY. I just forgot the &... THANK YOU.

Comment: just take the address of the parameter rather than the contents of the parameter example:  fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &emp[i].id);`  note the '&'.   The array references are fine as they degrade to the address of the first byte of the array,  However, the individual fields must be passed to `fscanf()` as the address of the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here fscanf takes memory address of the variables to store the read data into, just like scanf().
You need to put '&' in front of emp[i].id and all other data memebers except character arrays as array name itself gives address of first array members of the array.
So the code should be::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// structures
struct emp
{
    int id;
    char firstname[10];
    char lastname[10];
    int department;
    float salary;
} emp[10];


// function prototypes
// nothing here yet

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i = 0;
int choice;

if(argc != 2){

printf("Usage: %s input.txt\n", argv[0]);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

FILE* inputFile;


inputFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if(inputFile == NULL){
            printf("Error opening %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
// file is open now

// loop to save information from file into structure

 int num;

    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &num);


            for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &emp[i].id);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%s", emp[i].firstname);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%s", emp[i].lastname);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &emp[i].department);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%f", &emp[i].salary);

}


    printf("\n");
    printf("Welcome to the Employee Database!\n");
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    printf("Choose an option:\n");
    printf("1:   Print empid\n");
    printf("2:   Print ALL employees\n");
    printf("3:   Show ALL employees in department\n");
    printf("-1:  QUIT\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

// I have not set up the functions to perform the selection options yet 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: YEP. Something silly and simple. Thank you so much!